# Is there an intelligent way to know the name of the library to link to at compile time? (Linux/Kubuntu)

Tags: c++, compilation, linked-list, libraries

Please bear with me. I really want to know as I am curious about the answer:

Is there an intelligent way to know the name of the library to link to at compile time?

Allow me to give you an example that illustrates perfectly the reason for my question.

I am a C++ newbie. I am learning about compiling, linking and libraries like boost. I just discovered boost/filesystem and wanted to try it. Having had troubles compiling, I used the following minimalist code:

```
// file boost_example.cpp
 #include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

 #include <iostream>
```

int main()
{
        std::cout<<"Hello";
        return 0;
}

I tried to compile it, but being a newbie, I made a newbie mistake: I forgot to link to the proper library!
     `g++ boost_example.cpp -o run`
To be precise, I experienced the problem explained in [this chapter of this fine book](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html).
I knew I had boost installed (I was told to install it to compile another project). I tried to copy from the Makefile of that other project, but the following didn't work:
     `g++ boost_example.cpp -o run -lbooster`
     `g++ boost_example.cpp -o run -lboost`
Trying to make an educated guess from the #include line in the code, I tried the following to no avail:
     `g++ boost_example.cpp -o run -lboost_filesystem`
By that time, I had started to search the web frantically. I hate search engines because most of the time, you don't find what you're looking. I found the following but they didn't help but to waste my time:
[Boost library link problem under kubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=244593)
[C++/Boost linker errors](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=897996)

Since I am a RTFM kind of guy, I had actually checked the official documentation for the library I wanted to use: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm but I didn't find any compile information.

At some stage, I got inspired to check what I had actually installed on my system:

`$ locate boost_file
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.38.0`

Thus, I found the proper name of the library to link. The following worked:
     `g++ boost_example.cpp -o run -lboost_filesystem-mt`

Now, beside using (possibly) intelligent guess work and searching the web, is there a more intelligent way to find the name of the library to link to? I would never have guessed the library name `boost_filesystem-mt` given the header `"boost/filesystem.hpp"`.

What's worse: [boost_filesystem-mt is not mentioned anywhere](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:http://www.boost.org/+%22boost_filesystem-mt%22) on the official site! (I'm guessing it's distro/packaging dependent).

Again, I always make a point of RTFM before asking a question, and I found [this chapter of the aforementioned book](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_21.html), so I checked what I could find on my system at /usr/lib/:

`$ ls /usr/lib/boost
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.a           /usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.38.0   /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so
/usr/lib/libbooster.a                      /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libbooster.so                     /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt.a
/usr/lib/libbooster.so.0                   /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py25.a
/usr/lib/libbooster.so.0.0.0               /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py25.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a          /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py25.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so         /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py26.a
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.38.0  /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py26.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph-mt.a               /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py26.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_graph-mt.so              /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph-mt.so.1.38.0       /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.a           /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.so.1.38.0   /usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f-mt.a           /usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f-mt.so.1.38.0   /usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l-mt.a           /usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l-mt.so.1.38.0   /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99-mt.a            /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99-mt.so           /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99-mt.so.1.38.0    /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f-mt.a           /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f-mt.so.1.38.0   /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l-mt.a           /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l-mt.so.1.38.0   /usr/lib/libboost_wave-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1-mt.a            /usr/lib/libboost_wave-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1-mt.so           /usr/lib/libboost_wave-mt.so.1.38.0
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1-mt.so.1.38.0    /usr/lib/libboost_wserialization-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.a    /usr/lib/libboost_wserialization-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.so   /usr/lib/libboost_wserialization-mt.so.1.38.0`

And now I am scratching my head very hard, because I really don't know how to correlate the above to the [list of boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/).

I apologize for this long-winded example, but it perfectly illustrate my problem:

**Beside guesswork, searching the web, asking other people, trial and error, etc... is there a more intelligent way to find the name of the library one should link to?** Aren't those kind of things supposed to be documented somewhere?

I'm certainly interested in knowing the answer as far as boost is concerned, but my question is more generic and is applicable to any library.

Incidentally, I have a very similar question regarding the name of linux packages (be they .deb or .rpm). If I am told that to compile such or such software I need, say, PRCE or FooBar, how do I know precisely the name of the package to install? I know how to user apt-cache (for Kubuntu debs) but some package naming are not intuitive and I often end up installing packages I don't really need...

Comment: The answers are basically - no, there isn't, and yes, it should be documented.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. I made a note to remind me to file a bug report @ boost. http://linux.overshoot.tv/ticket/129

Comment: I guess people don't switch libraries frequently enough to have solved this basic problem, or to have an expectation of clearly documenting not just the header file needed, but the library name too. Meanwhile, people every day are wasting hours trying to figure out what to type after -l...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a brute-force method I sometimes use, but you do have to know what directories to look in for the library you need (/lib, /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib are the usual suspects). I've created a shell script I call "gnm," (short for "grep nm," the two utilities it uses) with the below contents. If you create such a text file, remember to make it executable (chmod +x gnm).

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 2 ] ; then
  echo Usage: $0 pattern file[s]
  exit
fi
pattern=$1
shift
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
  nm $1 | grep $pattern > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo $1
  fi
  shift
done
```

When I'm searching for a library that defines a particular symbol, I issue a command something like:

```
gnm symbol /usr/lib/*.a
```

For example, the source you mentioned gives me the following link errors:

```
boost_example.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
boost_example.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
boost_example.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
boost_example.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
boost_example.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
```

so I use the command:

```
gnm get_system_category /usr/lib/*.a
```

which reports:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a
/usr/lib/libboost_system.a
```

Trying the first of these results in the same errors, but the second one works:

```
g++ boost_example.cpp -lboost_system -o run
```

I don't know why I needed the system library where you needed filesystem; maybe different versions of Boost.

Comment: Nifty! Thanks. I'll try that next time.

Comment: I modified one line to nm $1 2> /dev/null | grep $pattern > /dev/null, saving me the "no symbol" outputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I just found the most intelligent and most official way (on my system) to figure out the link flag.
What follows is only valid for boost on a Debian or Debian derivative distribution (like Kubuntu in my case). The other replies might be more generic for any library on any system.

Depending on the boost version installed, you may have the following file on your Debian-like distribution:
`/usr/share/doc/libboost1.38-doc/README.Debian`
part of which reads:

```
--------

The following table shows which components use a library (shared or
static) and the corresponding "-l" flag.  Note that only the
multithreaded version of the libraries is shipped.

  Component              Link Flag                    Library Type
  ---------              ---------                    ------------
  Boost.Date_Time        -lboost_date_time-mt           static  shared
  Boost.Filesystem       -lboost_filesystem-mt          static  shared
  Boost.Graph            -lboost_graph-mt               static  shared
  Boost.IOStreams        -lboost_iostreams-mt           static  shared
  Boost.Math             -lboost_math_c99-mt            static  shared
                         -lboost_math_c99f-mt           static  shared
                         -lboost_math_c99l-mt           static  shared
  Boost.MPI              -lboost_mpi-mt                 static  shared
  Boost.Program_options  -lboost_program_options-mt     static  shared
  Boost.Python           -lboost_python-mt-py24         static  shared
                         -lboost_python-mt-py25         static  shared
  Boost.Regex            -lboost_regex-mt               static  shared
  Boost.Serialization    -lboost_serialization-mt       static  shared
                         -lboost_wserialization-mt      static  shared
  Boost.Signals          -lboost_signals-mt             static  shared
  Boost.System           -lboost_system-mt              static  shared
  Boost.Test             -lboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt    static  shared
                         -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt static  shared
  Boost.Thread           -lboost_thread-mt              static  shared
  Boost.Wave             -lboost_wave-mt                static  shared
```

One only had to find the proper place for the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html
Read about the installation there, all very clear.

Answer (score 1):

- One possibility is to check the file list of the rpm/deb package.
  On a Ubuntu system this could be done by issuing the following command:

> dpkg -L libboost-filesystem-dev

- Another possibility is to use pkg-config. It is a program that helps determine the compile flags for certain libraries (eventhough it does not support boost on Ubuntu)
- You could use Autoconf - a macro that checks for boost can be found [here](http://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4). Using Autoconf helps keeping your sources platform/distribution independent.

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate all these possibilities.